# Encode and store multiple variables in URL

Tags: php, url, variables, encode

I know this is possible and I researched it in many websites, but didn't find anything that could do exactly what I need.

I need to encode and store two parameters in URL and then retrieve it with $_GET method.

The parameters are not sensitive data. My purpose is mainly to obfuscate it, so the visitors can't read it without website accessing.

I have something like this:

**site.com/?name=john&food=banana%20split**

and I need it to become something like this:

**site.com/g57HT90dw8lC5p**

How can I do this? Thanks.

(Sorry for my bad english)

**EDIT:** I should explain it a bit more.

1. I know I'll have to use mod_rewrite and I got that part covered;
2. The second parameter is a complete sentence (with spaces, punctuation, etc.);
3. I need this to create a Christmas Card, so none of these parameters require secure methods. What I really need to store is just a **name** and a simple **message**.

Comment: by the looks of the url's you want mod_rewrite as well. and perhaps POST or sessions, to make them 'invisible'

Comment: mod_rewrite cannot hide your data you are rewriting, isn't it? :)

Comment: yes but hes changing the url, with out mod_rewrite g57HT90dw8lC5p is a directory\file

Comment: Yes, I know I need mod_rewrite and I got that pate covered. I just need to merge parameters and encode it. :)

Comment: depending on the message length you may have an issue with how long the url is. why not store the data in a db, and an id in the url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wrong approach - you said it is not sensitive so you better fix your code it will not be hacked if someone send you crafted data. Obfuscating prevents average users from doing changes but noone skilled be fooled by this. Also many browsers GET is limited (so can be configured PHP and server) so this may hit the wall sooner than you want. But if you insist you want this approach, you can put all variables into json_array, and then encode using base64.

```
$myData = array('foo'=>1, 'bar'=>'hax0r');
$arg = base64_encode( json_encode($myData) );

http://site.com/secret=$arg
```

and back:

```
$myData = json_decode( base64_decode( $_GET['secret'] ) );
```

But again - this is wrong by design.

Comment: it is wrong by design assuming you'd want any protection. But OP explicitly stated there is no sensitive data and only goal is to obfuscate, so I don't get why you think it is wrong by design?

Comment: If it is not sensitive why is he willing to do this in first place?

Comment: maybe just to have more funny- or cool-looking urls, or a birthday present. I don't know, but I don't think there's anything wrong with it, as long as you do your parameter checks *also*.

Comment: Sure, there may be a "for fun" explanation, still if he is doing it seriously, then it's just plain wrong for reasons I gave.

Comment: I edited my question, to explain my purpose a bit more. Yes, I don't need a secure method at all. I just want to obfuscate the data, because it will the text for a Christmas Card I'm doing. So I suppose that just encoding (and merging it in just one string) will be enough to do the trick. But is this may bring danger to my wbesite/server, I will not use it certainly. So, can I proceed with this piece of code?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense now :) Yes, you can go with this - it will not hurt your server any harder non-obfuscated arguments could.

Answer (score 2):

Append the two string values together; then use some encoding function like [str_rot13](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-rot13.php) or whatever

Answer (score 1):

You could just [uuencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.convert-uuencode.php) it.

On create

```
$converted = convert_uuencode('?name=john&food=banana');
// 6/VYA;64]:F]H;B9F;V]D/6)A;F%N80``
```

And on decoding

```
$query = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
// 6/VYA;64]:F]H;B9F;V]D/6)A;F%N80``
$real = convert_uudecode($query);
// ?name=john&food=banana
```

The point of uuencoding is to make data safe for network transmissions. It does not provide protection, but it will make them something else than clear text.

Answer (score 1):

Try these PHP functions [convert_uuencode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.convert-uuencode.php) and [convert_uudecode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.convert-uudecode.php)

**It is much safer than using only base64**

```
function encrypt_decrypt ($data, $encrypt) {
    if ($encrypt == true) {
        $output = base64_encode (convert_uuencode ($data));
    } else {
        $output = convert_uudecode (base64_decode ($data));
    }
    return $output;
}

$enc_txt = encrypt_decrypt ("name=john&food=banana%20split", true);
echo $enc_txt."\n";
// PTtGJU05M1VKO1ZBTilGOU87VjBdOEYlTjg2WUEpMyhQPFchTDo3MGAKYAo=
echo encrypt_decrypt ($enc_txt, false);
// name=john&food=banana%20split
```

Comment: I already got my problem solved, but thanks anyway, if I need this in the future, sure I will use this instead of base64. But why are these two functions safer than base64, btw?

Comment: because Base64 is very common and anyone can take the information and make a base64_decode to you URL and know what you are sending to your web page

Comment: you might even change some characters that only you know, so nobody else will know what you are sending

Comment: Oh nice! Thanks for the explanation. The purpose of this question was to help me on something that didn't required anything related to security. It was for a christmas card and the base64 was only to mask the query string, so it couldn't spoil the message to the user before the right time.

Answer (score 0):

Look at PHPs Doc [Base64Encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) . just encode the string, and decode it when reading the query.